# Would it technically be possible to write an os kernel in Swift?

Tags: swift, operating-system

Would it technically possible to write an OS kernel in Swift and assembly instead of assembly and C/C++? So I'm not asking if it would be suitable for kernel development I would like to know if it would be technically possible (as far as the computer is concerned)

Comment: No.  But we would love to see your attempts.

Comment: Yes. You can write an OS kernel in assembly, so assembly + a (possibly zero) amount of anything else is therefore possible.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: No; you need things like direct memory access (unless you also write a VM in the same package), so languages like Javascript are out.

Comment: @SLaks I'm pretty sure assembly has direct access to memory

Comment: @PeteKirkham: No; Javascript does not have pointers.

Comment: @SLaks I've programmed in assembly on an off for 30 odd years, you can use assembly for direct memory manipulation. You can then expose those features through whatever FFI your safe language uses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can write an OS kernel in any Turing-complete language and Swift is one. How suitable your language of choice for the task is a different matter completely.

Comment: Depending on how you define it, writing a kernel require more than just Turing-completeness.  For example, you cannot write a direct kernel in Javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure where the term Turin-complete comes from.  But my understanding is that Swift is written with C and therefore requires much in the way of C++ runtimes in order to function.  So, no, I don't think this is correct.

Comment: @SLaks you can theoretically write a Javascript compiler that compiles straight down to machine code, write a library that handle direct memory access, schedule tasks etc. A Turing-complete language means you can do whatever you want to do, without saying how efficiently you can do it.

Comment: @ZoffDino: But then the important parts of your kernel aren't written in Javascript.  Turing-completeness says nothing about external capabilities; for example, you can write a Turing-complete language with no ability to do disk IO.

Comment: @durbnpoisn *How suitable your language of choice for the task is a different matter completely.*

Comment: The other important consideration, besides being turing complete, is if the language is able to be compiled down to machine code. If you had a compiler for Javascript to compile to machine code, it would be possible to use the language for writing a kernel.

Comment: @SLaks http://bellard.org/jslinux/

Comment: @JoshAllemon: That's a virtual machine, not a kernel.

Comment: @SLaks right but you could write that linux kernel in js if the vm can be in js